# Does it ever make sense to have a caret or dollar sign in the middle of a regular expression?

Tags: regex

Consider the following regular expressions:

```
/xyz^abc/
/xyz$abc/
```

What will these match?

I know that

- the caret (`^`), when used at the beginning of a regex, matches the beginning of lines
- the dollar sign (`$`) , when used at the end of a regex, matches the end of lines
- the caret (`^`), when used as the first character of a character class, negates the class

I believe the given regular expressions won't ever match anything, but I am not sure.

Comment: I think it depends on the regex flavor. They could match the literal equivalents (`^` and `$` as literal characters).

Comment: @DanielHaley: Wouldn't they have to be escaped for that to happen?  Is there a regex flavour that would let an unescaped `^` match a literal `^`?

Comment: @RichieHindle - They work unescaped in GVIM. Haven't tried anything else yet. I would think most flavors would require escaping though.

Comment: @RichieHindle: POSIX BREs allow that; for example, `sed 's/o^b/xxx/' <<< foo^bar` will print `foxxxar`. See section 9.3.3 at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html.

Comment: Thanks for the much better example @ruakh.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depending on the options, a `^` or a `$` in the middle of a regular expression *can* cause a match:

```
>>> if re.search(r'xyz.^abc', "xyz\nabc", re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL):
...    print "Matched"
...
Matched
```

`MULTILINE` makes `^` match the start of a line, even if that line isn't at the start of the string.  `DOTALL` makes `.` match newlines.

(I can't find a way to make your exact examples match anything.)

Answer (score 5):

Those won't match anything. However:

```
/(xyz$|^xyz)/
```

That would match any line that begins OR ends with xyz.

**Update:**

Andy G points out that multi-line mode *may* find a match for your regex strings. But this only applies if the implementation is configured to support mid-string anchor matching.

This is from [Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) (my favorite place for learning & understanding regular expressions):

> If you have a string consisting of multiple lines, like first
>   line\nsecond line (where \n indicates a line break), it is often
>   desirable to work with lines, rather than the entire string.
>   Therefore, all the regex engines discussed in this tutorial have the
>   option to expand the meaning of both anchors. ^ can then match at the
>   start of the string (before the f in the above string), as well as
>   after each line break (between \n and s). Likewise, $ will still match
>   at the end of the string (after the last e), and also before every
>   line break (between e and \n).
>
> In text editors like EditPad Pro or GNU Emacs, and regex tools like
>   PowerGREP, the caret and dollar always match at the start and end of
>   each line. This makes sense because those applications are designed to
>   work with entire files, rather than short strings.
>
> In all programming languages and libraries discussed on this website ,
>   except Ruby, you have to explicitly activate this extended
>   functionality. It is traditionally called "multi-line mode". In Perl,
>   you do this by adding an m after the regex code, like this:
>   m/^regex$/m;. In .NET, the anchors match before and after newlines
>   when you specify RegexOptions.Multiline, such as in
>   Regex.Match("string", "regex", RegexOptions.Multiline).

Comment: I don't think multiline mode is relevant to the OP's examples, since `^` and `$` are zero-width assertions that don't swallow the newline; so, for example, the string `'abc\ndef'` matches the regex `/c$\n^d/`, but it wouldn't match `/c$d/` or `/c^d/`. **Edited to add:** Oh, I now see that RichieHindle posted an answer making this same point. :-)

Answer (score 0):

In Perl, `$` is also used for interpolation of string variables into the regex:

```
my $abc = 'pqr';
my $result = ('xyzpqr' =~ /xyz$abc/);   # $result is now true
```